# Как скинуть пароль при заходе в BIOS?

Tags: пароль

Попал в руки комп от друга, лежал без дела. Но есть одна проблема, он запоролен. Стоит Windows 7. При попытке захода в BIOS для установки Windows 10 требует пароль, манипуляции с батарейкой не привели к результату. Плата intel.

Просьба подсказать, как скинуть пароль или переустановить винду, т.к. на boot menu пароль.

Comment: Помимо батарейки ещё на мат. плате есть перемычка, по умолчанию она стоит в положении 1-2. Для обнуления BIOS необходимо переставить перемычку в положение 2-3 примерно на 15 секунд и затем вернуть обратно.

Comment: @MoloF про перемычки уж лучше читать в мануале, а не гадать про положения

Comment: @teran , вариантов всего два, ошибиться не удастся :^ , и в одном из вариантов оно уже стоит. Достаточно поменять местами и вернуть обратно через 15 секунд.